# Rails 5.2.x, updated to a FontAwesome kit from CDN - what do I need to add to my CSP to allow css and fonts?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, font-awesome-5

For anyone who is updating their FontAwesome from CDN to kit (free version), a couple of things I found useful when updating. Be sure to update your CSP with the following:

- add your kit src url to `CSP_DIRECTIVE_SCRIPT_SRC`
- add `https://kit-free.fontawesome.com` to your `CSP_DIRECTIVE_FONT_SRC`
- add `https://kit-free.fontawesome.com/releases/latest/css/free.min.css` to your `CSP_DIRECTIVE_STYLE_SRC`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add your kit src url to `CSP_DIRECTIVE_SCRIPT_SRC`
add `https://kit-free.fontawesome.com` to your `CSP_DIRECTIVE_FONT_SRC`
add `https://kit-free.fontawesome.com/releases/latest/css/free.min.css` to your `CSP_DIRECTIVE_STYLE_SRC`